# Error using Elaphe with GhostScript on Mac

Tags: python, macos, apache, python-imaging-library, ghostscript

I'm trying to setup elaphe on Mac. When I try generate some barcode using the terminal, with command `python + /.../file.py` elaphe works OK and generates the barcode correctly. But when I try to execute through web *(php)* I get the following error in the Apache's error logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib/barcode_generator/generator.py", line 19, in <module>
    code_39_image.save(str(random)+'.tif')
  File "/Users/x/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1406, in save
    self.load()
  File "/Users/x/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py", line 283, in load
    self.im = Ghostscript(self.tile, self.size, self.fp)
  **File "/Users/x/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py", line 72, in Ghostscript
    gs.write(s)**
```

If I were in Windows I would say it is a problem with the path and the program can't find the "gs.write" but in Mac I'm a rookie, I don't know if it's the same, nevertheless I've already include this 2 path:

```
export PATH=/Users/x/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

I would appreciate can give some ideas regarding this error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed via a symbolic link. Clearly was a PATH issue or hardcoded reference to the gs binary.

sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/gs /usr/bin/gs